# Можно ли получить превью файла в C#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-8.0

Допустим, имеем какую-то папку с файлами, в которой есть как картинки, так и файлы .txt и другие. Как получить превью для файла изображения, я понимаю. Просто уменьшить картинку. А вот как получить картинку текстового файла(обычно это картинка блокнота или тектового редактора, который используется для открытия этого файла).

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.icon.extractassociatedicon

Comment: Метка C#8 подразумевает, что используется .Net Core и желательна кроссплатформа?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov платформа Windows, да, .Net Core

Comment: Для Windows используйте мною приведенный метод